# Compute eigenvalues with Arpack

Tags: eigenvalue, arpack

I am using Arpack to compute the eigenvalues of the problem \lambda Mx = Ax with reverse shift method with complex shift. Then, I use znaupd e zneupd.
Everything seems to be ok. I wrote a function that takes the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors computed with Arpack and put them in the original problem:
\lambda Mx -Ax = residual. The norm of the residual is supposed to be almost zero or very small. Anyway, I obtain an error of 10^-3 that is quite high! Do you have any idea where the problem can come from?

Comment: Maybe, it is more appropriate to ask at scicomp.stackexchange.com See this: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10222/generalized-eigenvalue-problem-using-arpack The documentation advises to convert problem into standard form

Comment: Thank you, but my matrix M is real and symmetric... I'll try to ask to scicomp.stackexchange.com